# Returning a string in python

Tags: python

I need to get a string returned to the calling function of a script. A module called 'utils' has the function being called for a return value. Trying to learn how exactly this works/what should be expected. An explanation would be great.

utils module function:

```
def test_return():
    some = 'nice'
    print some

    return some
```

the caller script just need to print the return string. It's just a print statement:

```
print utils.test_return
```

Actual result:
`<function test_return at 0x7f9cff9d8a28>`

Expected result:
`nice`

Comment: Try `print utils.test_return()`

Comment: I noticed that. But I want to use only `utils.test_return`

Comment: @FutureB and the reason for using just `utils.test_return` is?

Comment: @FutureB the parenthesis are the only way to call the function. Without it only the function object is returned. But you could achieve this by setting a variable in `utils`.  `test_return = "nice"`

Comment: If you want that, try Ruby instead of Python. In Python, you need to use parentheses when calling a function.

Comment: @AllKnower, I see. However, setting a variable does not work for me. Is there a way to convert the function object to string output in that case, in the caller script? Sorry, if this does not make sense; I am a newbie.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, good to know. But I must use python

Comment: @FutureB Why don't you want to use parentheses? This might help you with a different solution. I feel like this is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: You **need to explain what you are trying to do** and why you don't want to use parentheses to call the function. As it is, we have given you the only possible solution.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I thought it would be an easy solution, so just talked about part of the script. Will be posting a different post explaining more details, since the entire theme could be different. Learned few things here though. And sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the print statement if you're just interested in getting 'nice'

code:

```
def test_return():
    some = 'nice'
    return some
```

output:

```
test_return()

Out: 'nice'
```

Comment: also you need to call with parenthesis 'test_return()'

Comment: I don't think it will work without correcting the indentation. you should also point out OP's mistake.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Had to use the `print` statement. Also, I don't want to call the function with `test_return()` I want to use `test_return`

Comment: Sorry about the indentation @mad_ !.

Comment: is there a reason you only want to use test_return?